# Entity framework issue with join two objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have following objects:

```
public class City
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CityTranslation> CityTranslations { get; set; }
    }
public class CityTranslation
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
        public string Translation { get; set; }

        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
```

City table contain default language value in Name field other translations are in CityTranslation table.
I am having problem to get value by language from this.
I am trying to execute following:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<City> GetAllByLanguage(string language)
        {
            if (language != "en")
            {
                var data = from c in context.Cities
                           join t in context.CityTranslations
                           on c.CityId equals t.CityId
                           && t.LanguageCode == language
                           select c;
            }
            else 
            {
                return dbSet.ToList();
            }
        }
```

But I am gettings compile error.

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

plus some casting errors.
What should I do to get value from translation table?

Comment: `t.CityId` is `int`, `t.LanguageCode == language` returns `boolean`. And `&&` is _logical AND_ operator. You can't use it wth `int` and `bool`.

Comment: Don't you mean `where t.LanguageCode == language`? You can also include the `WHERE` clause in lambda syntax in the reference to the table you're joining on e.g `join t in context.CityTranslations.Where(x => x.LanguageCode == language)
                           on c.CityId equals t.CityId`

Comment: `var data = from c in context.Cities
                           join t in context.CityTranslations.Where(x => x.LanguageCode == language)                            
                           on c.CityId equals t.CityId select c;` but I am getting casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second predicate should not be part of the join:

```
var data = from c in context.Cities
           join t in context.CityTranslations
               on c.CityId equals t.CityId
           where t.LanguageCode == language
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have spotted the issue, but you shouldn't even need the join - EF will handle it:

```
var data = from t in context.CityTranslations
           where t.LanguageCode == language
           select t.City;
```

Comment: Actually, I think this answer is better!

Comment: It doesn't return good translation. It still return City with translation from city table. Your answer return it from translation table.

Comment: There is no 'City' in the translation table.  Both methods achieve the same thing (and probably execute the same SQL) - you're doing a join and returning the 'City' part.  Neither will get you a translation unless you include `t.Translation` in any result.

Comment: @CharlesMager I have to reopen this question as I accepted answer a little too fast. Result city from this query still return me City object with default language. Can you help me to get translated object?

Comment: @1110 There is no `City` object with the translated name - what is it you actually want back?  It sounds like you just want all `CityTranslations` that match the `LanguageCode`, which is a far simpler query (it's as I wrote, but `select t` rather than `select t.City`.

Comment: I just want to call function and pass it `LanguageCode` and return a list of translated city names. Or statuses like I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753245/best-way-to-fetch-data-from-localized-database I need `IEnumerable<T>` that I can bind to dropdown list. Problem is that I want `City` list back but then can't get translation. If I return `Translation` it has `Translation` instead `Value` property.

Comment: It's not ideal, but try `select new City { CityId = t.CityId, Name = t.Translation }`

Comment: I tried that and that actually return what I want but as you said it is not ideal. Do you have any idea how to redesign this tables and objects to be better?

Comment: It's only not ideal in that it is potentially confusing - it's not actually a City from the database. I'd create a third object that has `Id` and `Name` called `LocalisedCity` or `CityViewModel` or something.

Answer (score 1):

For a join on multiple values you need to create composite key using anonymous types so your join statement needs to be something like

```
on new {t.CityId, t.languageCode} equals new {c.CityId, language}
```