# Best way to fetch data from localized database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-6

I created table structure to make statuses localized in database:

```
Status {StatusId, Value} -- Value in this table is status value in default language
StatusTranslation {StatusId, Language, TrasnlationValue} -- StatusId and Language are combined key
```

But I am having trouble to make this work in entity framework.
When default languege it is easy `Status.ToList()` but when I need translation I pass to the get method `de-CH` but I can't return translated Status.
What is the best way to map this using entity framework?
I thought that some of my methods work for this situation but in the end I find they are not.
This is objects in code:

```
public class Status 
    {
        public int StatusId{ get; set; }
        public string Value{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StatusTranslation > StatusTranslations { get; set; }
    }
public class StatusTranslation 
    {
        public int StatusId{ get; set; }
        public string Language{ get; set; }
        public string TrasnlationValue{ get; set; }

        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
var statuses = from c in context.Statuses
           join t in context.StatusTranslations
               on c.StatusId equals t.StatusId
           where t.Language == language

var statuses = from t in context.StatusTranslations
           where t.Language == language
           select t.Status;
```

Both of thees return me Status in default form (default language)
Return parameter should be `IEnumerable<Status>` meybe this is not possible.
**So I can return earthier `IEnumerable<Status>` or `IEnumerable<StatusTranslation>` but then this can't be one function or there is a hope?**

Comment: This seems a little unclear to me. Show us these methods you're having problems with and provide details of any exceptions/errors/unexpected behaviour. 'Fetching' data from a database shouldn't be your concern (as such) since you're using EF, so I think there's a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: I have added queries in question. I can't get `Status` with language that I need. Maybe my design is wrong or something. No errors problem is that I don't know how to fetch translated Statuses from this structure with EF (result should be bound in dropdown list (StatusId/Value)).